# something messy with .htaccess while using php include

Tags: php, .htaccess, include

I am currently working on a web application where i want to give user access to their profile by typing www.mysitename.com/username this is working fine with .htaccess but i also want the user to access other pages with clean urls by redirecting

http://www.mysitename.com/song-type-one.php?song=xyz to
http://www.mysitename.com/song-type-one.php/song/xyz

i used the rewrite rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./song-type-one.php?song=$1 
RewriteRule ^lok-songs/(.*)$ .song-type-one.php?song=$1
```

if i type the clean url now in the browser only my main content is loaded the css, javascript and my php include are not loaded. there might be something wrong with my .htaccess whats the best way to achieve all rules i want with .htaccess ?

Comment: What is the rewrite rule (if any) you're using to allow users to view their profile?  Sounds like that rule is being used unintentionally when you try to fetch the css, js, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this before it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If the file exists on disk it won't do your rewrite rule allowing the JS and images to be loaded normally.

Comment: i did it here is my .htaccess content <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./profile.php?username=$1 
  
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./lok-songs.php?song=$1 
 
  RewriteRule ^lok-songs/(.*)$ .lok-songs.php?song=$1  

    </IfModule> but its not woking...thanks for your reply